# Generic SQL Question (Big Query) - removing rows after a date that is different for each customer

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to remove all customer hits that I see on my site after they have registered. However, not all customers will register on the same day so I cannot simply filter on a specific date. I have a registration indicator of 1 or 0 and then a hit timestamp, along with unique indicators for the specific customers. I have tried this:

```
rank() over (partition by customer_id, registration_ind order by hit_timestamp asc) rnk
```

However, this still partitions by customer and isn't working for what I want.

Any help please?

THanks

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             min(case when registration_ind = 1 then hit_timestamp end) over (partition by customer_id) as registration_timestamp
      from t
     ) t
where registration_timestamp is null or
      hit_timestamp < registration_timestamp;
```

It returns all rows before the first registration timestamp.